# Flutter, IOS, how to prevent recording

Tags: ios, flutter

Currently there is a flutter app and it needs to be protect from screenshot or recording

but when I search about this, there is no way to implement this in a official way

but it seems there are some tricks (like 60fps? I know the concept but I don`t know how to implement this)

you can see the black screen when record the video on Netflix also (they prevent in some ways)

how could I achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a package called window manager which does just the thing that you are asking it restricts external apps from recording as well as does not allow screenshots to be taken
a detailed tutorial is given in this [article](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-disable-screenshot-and-video-capture#:%7E:text=After%20that%2C%20you%20need%20to,recording%20in%20Android%20and%20iOS.).

Comment: yup I know this I used this 'flutter_windowmanager" for Android. this doesn`t work for IOS

Comment: check out https://mrgulshanyadav.medium.com/prevent-screenshot-and-video-recording-in-flutter-93839325d66c this article on medium it explains how to enable it for ios as well.

Comment: did you see the comments in this article? what do you think?

Comment: i have not tested it for IOS so i am not sure if it will work but for android it worked so it could be that the person had some kind of problem in his build. But i think it should  work.and the other comments are just nonsense saying it only works for screenshots

Comment: Actually the second way of this article doesn\`t prevent recording.. it just hides the record menu button when user is still inside the app. but what if a user already started recording and launch the app? then it is recorded without any problem. so.. conclusion is it just works for android not ios

Comment: Try the secure application package which has support for iOS as well . It seems the window manager package is not going to provide any support for iOS.